# trouble with fopen and sprintf

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, printf

I understand the syntax for fopen in C is

```
fp = fopen ("file2.txt", "r");
```

My question is, if I wanted a txt file path in a char string that I made to be opened, could I do

```
char str[100];
FILE *fp;
sprintf(str, "\room%d.txt", 2);
fp = fopen (str, "r");
```

or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I doubt you actually want \r - maybe \\r or /r but not \r.

Comment: @DrC That's the answer :)

Comment: Note that you have to double up the backslash in the string literal to get a single backslash to the system.  Names such as `"\newfile"`, `"\test.data"`, `"\abc.txt"`, `"\very-old-data.txt"`, `"\backup.txt"`, `"\file.txt"`, `"\31-oct.txt"`, etc do not mean what you think; print the name out.  You can finesse the problem by using two backslashes or one forward slash instead.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the path that ended up in `str` was a path recognized by the OS, it would work fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But you should use the correct absolute path or relative path of the txt files you want to open.